# Value cannot be null. Parameter name: from WPF button binding datatrigger

Tags: wpf, button, datatrigger

I've been struggeling with this issue today when as soon as I try to bind a data trigger on a button I get this issue and I can't find our the issue. The button is contained in a listview which is bound to a dataset.

There is my button code:

```
<Button
                    Grid.Row="1"
                    Grid.Column="0"
                    Click="BtnAddToCart_Click" 
                    MinWidth="230">
                        <Button.Style>

                            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">

                                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="7,5,0,0"/>

                                <Style.Triggers>
                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=OrderQty, Converter={StaticResource GreaterThanZero}}" Value="True">
                                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                                    </DataTrigger>

                                </Style.Triggers>
                            </Style>

                        </Button.Style>
                        <Button.Template>
                            <ControlTemplate>
                                <WrapPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" >
                                    <WrapPanel.Style>
                                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type WrapPanel}">

                                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#ec3c42"/>
                                            <Setter Property="TextBlock.Foreground" Value="White"/>
                                            <Style.Triggers>
                                                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>
                                                    <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand"></Setter>
                                                    <Setter Property="TextBlock.Foreground"  Value="#ec3c42"></Setter>
                                                </Trigger>

                                            </Style.Triggers>

                                        </Style>
                                    </WrapPanel.Style>
                                    <WrapPanel.Resources>
                                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                                            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="10,10" />
                                            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
                                            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="15"/>
                                        </Style>

                                    </WrapPanel.Resources>
                                    <TextBlock   VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="Ajouter aux Commandes"></TextBlock>
                                    <fa:FontAwesome Visibility="Hidden" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Right"  Icon="check">
                                        <fa:FontAwesome.Triggers>
                                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=ShowAsChecked}" Value="true">
                                                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"></Setter>
                                            </DataTrigger>
                                        </fa:FontAwesome.Triggers>

                                    </fa:FontAwesome>
                                </WrapPanel>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Button.Template>
                    </Button>
```

The issue seems to happen when I add this piece of code:

```
<fa:FontAwesome.Triggers>
                                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=ShowAsChecked}" Value="true">
                                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"></Setter>
                                        </DataTrigger>
                                    </fa:FontAwesome.Triggers>
```

When I remove the trigger the code run as expected.

Even when I bind it to a property that is working on a different level it doesn't work.

I tried changing the binding to:

```
Binding="{Binding Path=OrderQty, Converter={StaticResource GreaterThanZero}}
```

and it's still giving me the error. I tried to look up some code example but didn't find anything about that issue (since the error is pretty common it's hard to tell what is going on).

Comment: Please, format your code properly and add code of ViewModel (or other object, representing a data context)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
<fa:FontAwesome Visibility="Hidden" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Icon="check">
    <fa:FontAwesome.Style>
            <Style TargetType="fa:FontAwesome">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=ShowAsChecked}" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"></Setter>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
    </fa:FontAwesome.Style>
</fa:FontAwesome>
```

Comment: It worked like a charm. I tried to do that at first but it didn't recognized the Visibility property. Looking at your code I realize that I forgot to specify the target type attribute of the style tag. Thanks for the help it was very apprciated.